# Image is not refreshing with new URL in angular

Tags: javascript, caching

For first time i am getting image properly, when i update the image it is not reflecting in DOM, in image url if i check latest updated image is there but not updating in DOM.

```
    imgurl+"?cache=" + new Date();
```

Previously i was appending with new Date so it was working, But now requirement has changed and there is no scope to use new date.

Any solution please

Comment: are you updating URL or only image is being updated on same URL?

Comment: can you please add some code, how you are updating?

Comment: make use of random number. Math.random()

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal updating image in same url

Comment: @ShenoyD'Souza cannot use anything after image name

Comment: Are you using the same image for the new images ? changing the image works for me. Check the plunker ---> https://run.plnkr.co/vYw4GuCoPcjHQWRB/

Answer (score 0):

If you need the image to change constantly for the production version of the website, you can configure your server to tell browsers not to cache the page.